VPX decode error raised, want to find out the reason
I'm new to using libvpx.
Currently, I'm testing with my sample webm file.
I checked the target file is truly webm file, then called webm_read_frame() to get single frame.
Then I fed the frame into vpx_codec_decode(), and it returns error code
VPX_CODEC_UNSUP_BITSTREAM.
I'm very new to codecs, so need help to figure out what this error means.
Referring to source code, it says :
The bitstream was unable to be parsed at the highest level. The decoder
is unable to proceed.This error SHOULD be treated as fatal to the
stream.
Thank you!

To whom it may concern, just check whether you should use VP8 or VP9...
